# Matching words with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

So for matching all words in a page of text, I'm using this:

```
new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)","ig");
```

The issue is, some of the things I need to match might be two words, like "green tea" for instance. So I tried this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\-?]+\\s[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)","ig");
```

but the issue is that it doesn't match every single double word combination, so maybe it'll match "in green", "tea leaves". I think thats how it works at least, all I know is it doesn't match "green tea".

Comment: Does interest you matching more than two words?

Comment: There's no magic pill here, because there's no way for a regex engine to know that the words "green tea" go together but "in green" don't, so you'll need to list all of the word combinations you want it to treat as a unit -- or do something after-the-fact instead.

Comment: So, just for clarification, an input of "I like green, tea is good" should return an array of `['I like', 'like green', 'green tea', 'tea is', 'is good', 'good']`?

Comment: Side note: `new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)","ig");` is incorrect (but in a harmless way, coincidentally), it's identical to `new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)","ig");` (note the ``\`` is missing), because the ``\`` is inside a string literal, you would need to escape it (with another ``\``). (It happens to be harmless because the `-` you were trying to escape is at the end of the character class, so it doesn't need escaping.) This is one of many reasons not to use `new RegExp` and a string when you can avoid it: Just use a regex literal: `/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/ig/`

Comment: Er, ignore the final `/` on that comment. :-)

Comment: If you desired matches according @Jonathan's comment, you can use a [lookahead for capturing the overlapping combinations](https://regex101.com/r/fY8cU2/1). See [demo at ideone](https://jsfiddle.net/hd1owbu7/).

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic pill here, because there's no way for a regex engine to know that the words "green tea" go together but "in green" don't, so you'll need to list all of the word combinations you want it to treat as a unit — or do something before-or-after-the-fact instead.

For instance, this will match words in text but treat "green tea" as a single match:

```js
var rex = /(green tea)|([a-zA-Z0-9\-']+)/ig;
var str = "I like green tea, don't you?";
console.log(str.match(rex));
```

The `|` is an *alternation* meaning "try to match any of these alternatives" (earlier alternatives are preferred to later ones).

Obviously that would get cumbersome really quickly, though, so you may need to look beyond regex, either pre-processing or post-processing to handle your list of desired two-word "words."

---

Note: I added `'` to the second half of that, since otherwise "don't" was read as "don" and "t".

Answer (score 1):

First, as always, [regexp101](https://regex101.com/#javascript) is your friend!  :)

Second, [a-zA-z0-9] is equivalent to \w.  And if you want to add dashes and question marks your definition of a 'word' (as it appears you do), you can use [\w-?].

Finally, you probably want a non-capturing group like this:

```
'((?:[\w-?]+(?:\s[\w-?]+)*))'
```

which says "find a word, followed by zero or more 'space characters + word' groups".

Tweak in regex101 to taste.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How does that help with matching "green tea" but not "in green"?

Comment: You are correct: the original question wasn't well posed.  It appears that Mr. Slotsky will have to provide special cases.  But `\w+(?:\s\w+)*` is so idiomatic (as is the need for regex101) that it bears repeating.

Comment: Can't say I find the question unclear on that point at all. The other points (which are useful) are *comments*, not an answer.